# Upload a picture to Google Cloud Storage via macOS terminal

Tags: bash, macos, firebase, google-cloud-storage

Is there a way to upload pictures from a local folder to Google Cloud Storage using bash commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ['curl' tool to send REST API call](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) (click on REST API) to upload objects to Google Cloud Storage.